Are there any good Jewish books which speak on trauma and emotional pain and then tie in lessons taken from Jewish sources?
Trauma and emotional pain are both common themes of both the Jewish and human experience.
I was curious if there were any good books which dive in deep on this topic and cite references from the Talmud and Torah and even just opinions/anecdotes from the sages on how a Jew should best deal with the issue of pain and trauma?
This is an open ended question but I'll cite specific examples of the topics I mean.

The spiritual significance of emotional pain and trauma
How a Jew should best handle such issues (both for themselves or for others)
The wisdom of respected sages and Rabbis on the topic
Why it seems some people seem to suffer more than others given the same circumstances
etc.


I suggest that you take a look at some of the works of Rabbi Dr. Abraham J. Twerski, who was both a rabbi from an old and respected rabbinic family and a psychiatrist specializing in addictions, and who wrote numerous books on these topics.  (According to Wikipedia, he wrote over 90 books.)
As for which book to read first, that really just depends on what appeals to you.  He said himself that he didn't so much write 45 books (or whatever number he was up to at the time), as he wrote the same book 45 times. They all tend to talk about the same ideas. So whichever one appeals to you is a great place to start.
That said, "When Do The Good Things Start?" is full of wisdom and insight, and if you like Charlie Brown and his friends, that's an added bonus.

Rabbi Dr. Twerski’s books are great.  Other books on this topic include the following:

Yissurim:  A Blessing in Disguise by Leib Gershon Seligson;
Pain is a Reality, Suffering is a Choice by Rabbi Asher Resnick;
The Holy Fire by Nehemia Polen;
Finding Light in the Darkness by Shaul Rosenblatt; and
Why God Why by Rabbi Gershon Schusterman.


Garden of the Souls is a small book on suffering from a Breslov perspective. Not to be confused with the Garden series from R Shalom Arush.
